# HackerEarth exercise incorrect result

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a [problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/practice-problems/algorithm/n-co-ordinates-pair-practice/) from HackerEarth but after submitting my code, it says that all of my results are incorrect. I cannot see the difference between the correct output and my output because that option is not working on the site. But I took a look at my output and the correct result and they seem to be the same.
This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {


    class Point {
        int x;
        int y;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Point point = (Point) o;

            if (x != point.x) return false;
            return y == point.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = x;
            result = 31 * result + y;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Point, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            Point point = new TestClass().new Point(x, y);
            Integer value = map.get(point);
            if (value == null) {
                map.put(point, 1);
            } else map.put(point, value + 1);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Comparator<Map.Entry<Point, Integer>> lexicoComparator = (e1, e2) -> {
            return e1.getKey().x - e2.getKey().x;
        };

        map.entrySet().
                stream().
                sorted(lexicoComparator).
                forEach(entry -> sb.append(entry.getKey().x + " " + entry.getKey().y + " " + entry.getValue() + "\n"));
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
        System.out.print(sb);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, did you read the description carefully? it says: "Print the coordinate points in the Lexicographical order" which means that you should consider coordinate y and not just x

Comment: lol, this was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you should take into account coordinate `y` as well, not just `x` because description says:

> Print the coordinate points in the Lexicographical order

So instead of writing:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Point, Integer>> lexicoComparator = (e1, e2) -> {
            return e1.getKey().x - e2.getKey().x;
        };
```

...you could write something like:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Point, Integer>> lexicoComparator = (e1, e2) -> {
            Point p1 = e1.getKey();
            Point p2 = e2.getKey();
            if (p1.x == p2.x){
                if (p1.y > p2.y)
                    return 1;
                if (p1.y == p2.y)
                    return 0;
                return -1;
            }
            if (p1.x > p2.x)
                return 1;
            return -1;
        };
```

You may probably wonder why I do not just subtract the `x` and `y` coordinates like in other `compareTo` examples. That's because the description says:

> -10^9<= x,y <=10^9

What this means is that subtracting coordinates you could get a nice overflow(not necessarily but still the best approach is to compare them with conditionals).

Full solution:

```
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {


    class Point {
        int x;
        int y;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Point point = (Point) o;

            if (x != point.x) return false;
            return y == point.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = x;
            result = 31 * result + y;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Point, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            Point point = new TestClass().new Point(x, y);
            Integer value = map.get(point);
            if (value == null) {
                map.put(point, 1);
            } else map.put(point, value + 1);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Comparator<Map.Entry<Point, Integer>> lexicoComparator = (e1, e2) -> {
            Point p1 = e1.getKey();
            Point p2 = e2.getKey();
            if (p1.x == p2.x){
                if (p1.y > p2.y)
                    return 1;
                if (p1.y == p2.y)
                    return 0;
                return -1;
            }
            if (p1.x > p2.x)
                return 1;
            return -1;
        };

        map.entrySet().
                stream().
                sorted(lexicoComparator).
                forEach(entry -> sb.append(entry.getKey().x + " " + entry.getKey().y + " " + entry.getValue() + "\n"));
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
        System.out.print(sb);
    }

}
```